# Nashorn. Binding native Java objects?

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, nashorn

I'd like to put native Java objects into the ScriptEngine bindings for easier access.
I mean to avoid lots of Java.type(...).
I tried in that way.

```
jsEngine.getContext().getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).put("manager", Manager.getInstance());
```

But that's failed with error *"Manager has no such function "funcName" in eval...".*

Is it possible at all?

**UPD:**
Example code

```
public class ManagerClass {

    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Static");
    }
}

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        final ScriptEngine s = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
        s.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).put("manager", new ManagerClass());
        s.eval("manager.test(); manager.test2();");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: Nashorn was the name of a tank destroyer in WW2.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. Can you show the scripting side, and more context surrounding the embedding side?

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell Surely. I've appended very simple code.

Comment: `class Manager` is not `public`, and `test` is not part of any interface implemented by `Manager` and does not override a `public` method in a `public` base class, so unless you use `setAccessible` to violate Java's normal scoping rules, `Manager.test` shouldn't be invokable reflectively.

Comment: @MikeSamuel That's it! I've missed out that thing, thanks a lot. And by the way, how can i call **static** method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.
The correct way is

```
 s.eval("manager.test(); manager.class.static.test2();");
```